# I need help installing Avatarify Python

Tags: python, pip, conda, miniconda, mamba

So I have a GeForce GTX 1660 Ti (6GB Dedicated graphics) running windows 11 pro but for some reason, Avataryfy Python gets stack at Solving Environment.

```
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-1.1.1t-h2bbff1b_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-22.3.1-py37haa95532_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.7.16-h6244533_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-65.6.3-py37haa95532_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.40.1-h2bbff1b_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.38.4-py37haa95532_0
  wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37haa95532_2



Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate avatarify
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
```

I managed to get past this by pressing Ctrl + C but after installing everything successfully, I get this error when I run (run_windows.bat)

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "afy/cam_fomm.py", line 4, in <module> import yaml ModuleNotFoundError: 
No module named 'yaml'
```

I need help guys
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LwZT.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What command did you run that gave each output? Is `afy/camm_fomm.py` your own code? If so, you should [edit] your question to include it. By pressing Ctrl+C, you cancelled the operation. IDK if that is your problem, but you probably need to try again and wait longer.

Comment: Without the commands run, we don't know what was done.

Comment: I added a photo to further clarify my point

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to install Avatarify in my Windows 11 home.
There are these three commands that I had run:

1. `git clone https://github.com/alievk/avatarify-python.git`
2. `cd  avatarify-python`
3. `scripts\install_windows.bat`

The command number three was getting stuck on **Solving environment:|** |

I did a bit of research and found the answer here [A Faster Solver for Conda: Libmamba](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community)

So basically what you do is run these three codes:

1. `conda update -n base conda`
2. `conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver`
3. `conda config --set solver libmamba`

After they have run successfully, close the **anaconda prompt**

Then open **anaconda prompt** again and run `scripts\install_windows.bat`

It should work now

Answer (score 0):

After that how can i fix this error? [option --use-feature: invalid choice: '2020-resolver' (choose from 'fast-deps', 'truststore', 'no-binary-enable-wheel-cache')]

```
Executing transaction: done
The system cannot find the file specified.
Cloning into 'fomm'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 211, done.
remote: Total 211 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 211
Receiving objects: 100% (211/211), 58.16 MiB | 547.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (108/108), done.

Usage:
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

    option --use-feature: invalid choice: '2020-resolver' (choose from 'fast-deps', 'truststore', 'no-binary-enable-wheel-cache')
```

Comment: Can you ask this as a separate question with more context as to the setup you have and the step/command that is failing?